# How to get grub command data to a variable?

Tags: grub2

I have a problem in grub2 to a variable.

grub is bash like, but something id different.

In grub script or shell mode. I can't do like this:

```
diskinformation=$(ls)
or
set diskinformation=$(ls)
```

Is there someway to get a grub command to a variable?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be no such generic way.

The `search` command has a specific `--set` option that makes the command output its result into the variable that was specified with that option. If a generic mechanism similar to what you're thinking was available, then there would be no need to have the `--set` option with the `search` command.

Comment: Thanks you so much.